# How to define function with overloads to have exactly 1 or 2 arguments which types depend on used string literal

Tags: typescript, overloading, typescript-generics

I wanna implement a `emitEvent(event, extra?)` function that will be constraint by string literal enum of known string, like `POPUP_OPEN`,`POPUP_CLOSED` etc. This function accepts 2nd argument which is again an explicitly defined dictionary shape, which can only be used with particular event keys.

Here is the dictionary for all known events:

```
interface Events {
    POPUP_OPEN: {name:'POPUP_OPEN',extra: {count:number}},
    POPUP_CLOSED: {name:'POPUP_CLOSED'},
    AD_BLOCKER_ON: {name:'AD_BLOCKER_ON', extra: {serviceName:string}},
    AD_BLOCKER_OFF: {name:'AD_BLOCKER_OFF'}
}
```

**Usage with demanded type constraints:**

```
// $ExpectType  {object: string; action: string; value: string;}
const t1 = emitEvent('POPUP_CLOSED')

// $ExpectError -> no extra argument allowed
const t11 = emitEvent('POPUP_CLOSED', {what:'bad'})

// $ExpectType  {object: string;action: string;foo: string; count: number;}  
const t2 = emitEvent('POPUP_OPEN',{count: 1231})

// $ExpectError -> extra argument is missing
const t22 = emitEvent('POPUP_OPEN')
```

**My implementation:**

This implementation has one big issue, for dictionary value, which has `extra` defined, TS wont complaint when it's not defined

```
// ✅ NO ERROR
const t2 = emitEvent('POPUP_OPEN',{count: 1231})
// ✅ Error
const t2 = emitEvent('POPUP_OPEN',{})
// NO ERROR -> THIS SHOULD ERROR !
const t2 = emitEvent('POPUP_OPEN')
```

**Implementation:**

```
type ParsedEvent<Extra = void> = Extra extends object ? BaseParsedEvents & Extra : BaseParsedEvents

type BaseParsedEvents = {
  object:string
  action:string
  value:string
}

type KnownEvents = keyof Events
type GetExtras<T> = T extends {name: infer N, extra: infer E} ? E : never;

function emitEvent<T extends KnownEvents>(event:T): ParsedEvent
function emitEvent<T extends KnownEvents, E extends GetExtras<Events[T]>>(event:T, extra: E): ParsedEvent<E>
function emitEvent<T extends string, E extends object>(event:T, extra?: E) {
  const parsedEmit = parse(event)
  return {...parsedEmit,...extra}
}


function parse(event:string): BaseParsedEvents {
    const [object,action,value] = event.split('_')  
    return {object,action,value}
}
```

Overall I'm afraid this is not possible to implement, but hopefully I'm wrong :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [tuples in rest parameters](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897) instead of overloads to get the function to accept a variable number of arguments. `GetExtras` will either return a tuple with a single `E` element or the empty tuple. We can then spread `GetExtras` as the spread parameter of the function:

```
interface Events {
    POPUP_OPEN: {name:'POPUP_OPEN',extra: {count:number}},
    POPUP_CLOSED: {name:'POPUP_CLOSED'},
    AD_BLOCKER_ON: {name:'AD_BLOCKER_ON', extra: {serviceName:string}},
    AD_BLOCKER_OFF: {name:'AD_BLOCKER_OFF'}
}


// $ExpectType  {object: string; action: string; value: string;}
const t1 = emitEvent('POPUP_CLOSED')

// ✅ NO ERROR
const t21 = emitEvent('POPUP_OPEN',{count: 1231})
// ✅ Error
const t213 = emitEvent('POPUP_OPEN',{})
// ✅  ERROR  as expected
const t223 = emitEvent('POPUP_OPEN')


type ParsedEvent<Extra extends [object] | [] = []> = Extra extends [infer E] ? BaseParsedEvents & E : BaseParsedEvents

type BaseParsedEvents = {
  object:string
  action:string
  value:string
}

type KnownEvents = keyof Events
type GetExtras<T> = T extends {name: infer N, extra: infer E} ? [E] : [];

function emitEvent<T extends KnownEvents, E extends GetExtras<Events[T]>>(event:T, ...extra: E): ParsedEvent<E>
function emitEvent<T extends string, E extends object>(event:T, extra?: E) {
  const parsedEmit = parse(event)
  return {...parsedEmit,...extra}
}


function parse(event:string): BaseParsedEvents {
    const [object,action,value] = event.split('_')  
    return {object,action,value}
}
```

[play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIDcLgM7IN4BQyxyACgPKkCqpA+pagHIBc+IcAthMwOQXV0GjHgBoIADzBQ4rPAgD2AV3DMQijgCNoAX20iiJfjVoBhADLkAyqgAis9l15G65q7Z56DxAII3aAIQsTAGlUACV6FjZObh5fAKDQiPJhEWQJKRl8bGh0YCRGGOZsKVAAc119EmR4wPIQ8PoAMSb7Iri-Oobklo8CbQJBgHoh5AASVHEABwgEMAAVAE8Z4jx5DQArWbBWEqhygG5kRDBgeRBd0pAyo-Q4ABtFbmQ9w4GFEBLkMABGZABedIcYBgDBYMAACj4lGMrmsNh4AEphqNAKDkyEY5DQYTC5DCBA+XzAACY-oCIMDQZhwFDnPRSExRHIlCpkD9iQBmH7aZEjZDo1BQKDyKAE85E0kcgFAkFgmnQgT0xkiPA8gh89HY3FhYhwXASGZzCAAEzFnzA32JnOlFNl1MhCuMQiRgwIYGWKFIcCgOWNcrAAB5Jpl0pIsMbcABtdZbOYAXWQAB9kJGE4DUwA+aXB6ShyAgCMp0AwaBoBMAfmQ-j1EC9PpN-twADI0MhWNWcnXfY3Bu6Vh3a97u-bcIDCMQY9tilcygYTmcLq9rgY7o9uEvZwM3R7kMEQPIAO4gRvSgDWEEW8hgaBH25WAHEIKDJNJsAH5lnAfM8+HcHgHM8xalowaQZNIrBAVAaDaMglaRqgCasKmByDDAyhzAuMpUuC74-gWuB7oex4jmkqB4YWj7Ppkb6NpG8xxhmGYQhA9rMPMaQAHRcWBWSoIirBdg29pBhmBBoSAGHnFh-q4Rkv4vDOpHkbgk5zExLHgmxoEvnA5asHx+AGISFpTEODaUtKpn1sx9rIsQUBPooUAgPgXEcVZ3aUiIbk8QMW5iehpxSR5EA2ZpG78VWNaCX6I6GdUxkpqpYAiPO5wiKuTxpuk9ocdgUz3CCUK0EixBeMgDlgE5LlrJs2ypZJIAZQ8Tx+UAA)

Comment: nice! also the overload can be removed with this implementation, but with removal, we would have to manually pick only first item from rest array, which is not very nice solution indeed...

```ts
function emitEvent<T extends KnownEvents, E extends GetExtras<Events[T]>>(event:T, ...extra: E) {
  const parsedEmit = parse(event)
  return {...parsedEmit,...extra[0]}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about restricting your first function overload declaration to events, that do not include an `extra` property?

```
// define events, that do not have extra property
// "POPUP_CLOSED" | "AD_BLOCKER_OFF"
type KnownEventsWithoutExtra = {
  [K in keyof Events]: Events[K] extends { name: string; extra: object }
    ? never
    : K
}[keyof Events];

// single argument overload is restricted to above events
function emitEvent<T extends KnownEventsWithoutExtra>(event: T): ParsedEvent;

// will error now
const t4 = emitEvent("POPUP_OPEN");
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIDcLgM7IN4BQyyACgPIkCqJA+hagHIBc+yIcAthCwETlW16DHgG5kEAB5gocFnmQIA9gFdwLEMo4AjaMgC++kUVIVqNAMIAZMgGVUAETltO3ZH1O0rthz0PGAgvY0AELW5gDSqABKdMys7Fy8gSFhkTFkwmKS0rKs2NDowEgMLizY0qAA5vp+xMmhZBHRdABiLU4Jrjz1qc1kbb56RnoEBAD0Y8iAoOTIDGRoUVFkUQRKIOXIYABMyAC84hzAYBhYYAAU7gJ0JIw8ADSsSqpgLACMWwDMr-oAlEYT0zQUCgiigq0U6zAmw+ewORxO4Au-DMQnu+D0f3Gk0AvBuACr25gsllFkABaAB8yAAKgAJACSNmQNmpZEolnshOWyAAhODIZsACywiCHY6YRGXFE3YSYghgACeAAcUCQ4FB8gATBFgAA8qCkMlh6EUwHVFP2epy4ikWHVuEUWgAVhAEGBjAB+ZDBOD5FVqiCasVgXAAMjQ+rgxhYXp9qo1WuwRllipQ0Ygvrjgdw+0IxHtTpdZQqIEqRmIiDAwAhhagVVLyHQcAANspXOUa8Xhon5UrkOEQIoAO4geOwgDWEDlihgaEzRm7KAA4hBjuHsNrKWaqVbICBbfFSshQDBdAwsuGWEfdKgah7r+oIJgoF3k73+0P4wB1I4ACxUK8t2bGAA2uEh4gMg46TtO8YALosPGIEwduNq4PInTVrW24yCwebOlCIzEMQHogA+0DGMQLDhAQehAZBU4zqc2AwYmMCqC6lbgcK8KBuuyG7rgfaDsOmZfmAv7KP+MhkmcpFqFSPwsOm-pakYrEgOxEJwqKpy8dkKGvkJ8YPNeen8cgS6Sd6uqZkBlIwWS0nGLJLxUncTnnmgBAKaQsbKTxqBkqpbEVppXHaeAunWmZbZVMZfF7rhLrSc5LCUg82QyG68E-PgxhrBsCq+ZqIqwoVfoyYGmLEFAy7KFA4HyAAdM1ZVxiKDzNY1GVwH4IwEGpGnga1EAVacGHFt5qZKQGjG5cQ+VQkBiVgA85YcQ8DbNhASH7M5jXYAqjZHBcNA8FVyA1WAdUNcgy2rYNG1Ni2vUEEAA)

Comment: I was trying to do that initially via mapped type, but wasn't able to do it. Sometimes I'm just overcomplicating things I guess :D this definitely works! Although overload implementation is more generic, so I'll mark that as a solution. Thanks!